# Fabric Api is installed on the version above. IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

i don't understand how to solve it. Build.gradle & properties is normal, but Fabric Api install a version above.

and I understand that he asks for a higher version of Minecraft. But I need 1,18,1

**This a log**

````
[11:41:49] [main/WARN] (FabricLoader/Resolution) Mod resolution failed
[11:41:49] [main/INFO] (FabricLoader/Resolution) Immediate reason: [HARD_DEP_INCOMPATIBLE_PRESELECTED fabric 0.47.8+1.18.2 {depends minecraft @ [~1.18.2-alpha.22.5.a]}, ROOT_FORCELOAD_SINGLE fabric 0.47.8+1.18.2]
[11:41:49] [main/INFO] (FabricLoader/Resolution) Reason: [HARD_DEP fabric 0.47.8+1.18.2 {depends minecraft @ [~1.18.2-alpha.22.5.a]}]
[11:41:49] [main/INFO] (FabricLoader/Resolution) Fix: add [], remove [], replace [[fabric 0.47.8+1.18.2] -> add:fabric 1 ([(-∞,∞)])]
[11:41:49] [main/ERROR] (FabricLoader) Incompatible mod set!
 net.fabricmc.loader.impl.FormattedException: Mod resolution encountered an incompatible mod set!
A potential solution has been determined:
     - Replace mod 'Fabric API' (fabric) 0.47.8+1.18.2 with any version that is compatible with:
         - minecraft 1.18.1
Unmet dependency listing:
     - Mod 'Fabric API' (fabric) 0.47.8+1.18.2 requires any version between 1.18.2-alpha.22.5.a (inclusive) and 1.19- (exclusive) of 'Minecraft' (minecraft), but only the wrong version is present: 1.18.1!
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.FabricLoaderImpl.load(FabricLoaderImpl.java:190) ~[fabric-loader-0.14.8.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.Knot.init(Knot.java:148) ~[fabric-loader-0.14.8.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.Knot.launch(Knot.java:68) [fabric-loader-0.14.8.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotClient.main(KnotClient.java:23) [fabric-loader-0.14.8.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.devlaunchinjector.Main.main(Main.java:86) [dev-launch-injector-0.2.1+build.8.jar:?]

Process finished with exit code 1```
````

Answer (score 1):

You need a matching version of the Fabric API.

The version you selected `requires any version between 1.18.2-alpha.22.5.a`.
Therefor you can't use it for Minecraft 1.18.1 and you need to get an older version of Fabric.

From the [Fabric Website](https://fabricmc.net/develop/) I can see that you should use the fabric version `0.46.6+1.18`. Update you gradle file as shown on this website.

Comment: not working and error is same. this may happen from a "Minecraft Dev" Plugin

Comment: or due to closing from Task Manager

Comment: The error cannot be the same! If you have downgraded to an older version at least the version numbers must have changed. Can you provide the error message from version `0.46.6+1.18`?